# When I am running java program manually from terminal it is working fine but it is not working when i am running from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, bash, sqoop

My program is not running from eclipse but it is running through terminal in ubuntu.

Below is the shell script that i am running in java

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Running sqoop commands

s="$(sqoop help)"

echo "$s"
```

Below is the java code

```
package flexibility;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Flex {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String s = null;
        String line = "";
        String sqoopCommand = "sqoop help";

        try {

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/avinash/sqoop.sh");
            p.waitFor();

            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");

            }
            while ((line = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");

            }
            System.out.println("### " + output);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

error message :

/home/avinash/sqoop.sh: line 5: sqoop: command not found

Comment: i havent used eclipse, but you might have to manually export the environment into Eclipse's path. Just throwing suggestions.

Comment: Use the full path name for `sqoop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the command "sh /home/avinash/sqoop.sh". I feel since the ubuntu isn't aware what kind of file it is,It's clearly throwing command not found error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is from your script. Not from Eclipse.

Eclipse (or the JVM to be more precise) does not know about the environment variables or working directory of the script. In contrast: If you run the script from command line environment variables (e.g. PATH) or working directory are known.

You can use method `Runtime.exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)` to specify this in your Java code. So I guess this should work:

```
Process p = 
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/avinash/sqoop.sh", null, new File("/home/avinash/"));
```